# python seaborn set xlim and ylim for jointplot and get rid of distribution information above and on right side

Tags: python, seaborn

Hello I am new to Python and to Seaborn. I would just like to set x-limits and y-limits to a Seaborn jointplot. Furthermore I would like to plot this figure without the distribution information above and at the right side of the main plot. How can I do that? I am trying something like this:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt from
matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter 
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")


xData = np.random.rand(100,1)*5 
yData = np.random.rand(100,1)*10


xlim = [-15 15] 
ylim = [-20 20]

g = sns.jointplot(xData, yData, kind="hex", color="b", xlim, ylim)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify it clear enough. I want to use the jointplot with hex-kind `kind="hex"`. And such a plot is unfortunately not available with `kdeplot`. Furthermore I tried to apply set_xlim and set_ylim on the axes via `g = sns.jointplot(xData, yData, kind="hex") `, `axes = g.axes` and `axes.set_ylim(20)` but there is an error, because jointgrid has no axes attribute.

Comment: In the documentation of the jointplot it is written to use two tuples for x and y limits but I don't understand with which syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint axes of a seaborn `jointplot` of `kind="hex"` is a matplotlib `hexbin` plot. Hence you can just call `plt.hexbin(xData, yData)`.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xData = np.random.rand(100,1)*5 
yData = np.random.rand(100,1)*10

xlim = [-5, 10] 
ylim = [-5, 15]

plt.hexbin(xData, yData, gridsize=10)
plt.xlim(xlim)
plt.ylim(ylim)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

`xlim` and `ylim` should be tuples. hence your code should be:

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt from
matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter 
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")

xData = np.random.rand(100,1)*5 
yData = np.random.rand(100,1)*10

g = sns.jointplot(xData, yData, kind="hex", color="b", xlim = (-15,15), ylim = (-20,20))
```